# CString values gets truncated during 64bit casting

Tags: c++, mfc

When I cast from Ulong64 to cstring value gets truncated in 64 bit, Can any one help me on this?

```
HMONITOR hmonitor64;  // Hmonitor decl  
hmonitor64 = (HMONITOR)0x0000000300290eaf;// initialize to big value
ULONG64 lmonitor64;
CString strMonitor64;
lmonitor64 = (ULONG64)hmonitor64; // typecasted to long 
strMonitor64.Format(_T("%lu"), lmonitor64);  // value gets truncated in cstring
```

Comment: Please, format your source code. (Use tool button '{}' of the editor.)

Comment: Without any research I would guess you have to use `"%llu"`. `long` means 32 bits in Windows/VC even on 64 bit platforms. So, you have to use `long long unsigned` or (as you did) `ULONG64`.

Comment: Truncation also happens in 32-bit code. You just don't notice, because `HMONITOR` is 32 bits wide in 32-bit code.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to format `ULONG64` is the following:

```
HMONITOR hmonitor64;  // Hmonitor decl  
hmonitor64 = (HMONITOR)0x0000000300290eaf;// initialize to big value
ULONG64 lmonitor64;
CString strMonitor64;
lmonitor64 = (ULONG64)hmonitor64; // typecasted to long 
strMonitor64.Format(_T("%I64u"), lmonitor64);  // value gets truncated in cstring
```